# Session becoming Null after Response.redirect

Tags: asp.net, database, session, null

I set two sessions which I fill from a database:

> ```
>     Session("username") = reader.Item("user_name").ToString 
>     Session("department") = reader.Item("user_department").ToString
> ```

to add restrictions depending on department the user is signing in from (IT department, customer service, etc..)

Sessions are readable from the form LogIn.aspx to the form Default.aspx

But in other pages:

> ```
>     IF Session("Department")<>"IT"
>     Response.Redirect("LogIn.aspx")
>     End If
> ```

This redirects to LogIn.aspx and Session("Department") equals Nothing

Any idea on why it is doing so? I tried searching for something missing in my code and I couldn't find anything.

Comment: check for session timeout time..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
IF Session("Department")<>"IT"
```

use this

```
IF Session("department")<>"IT"
```

spell mistake( Keys are case sensitive).

And use if condition with safety like this

```
If Session("department") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not Session("department").ToString().Equals("IT") Then
```

Comment: Yes I fixed the session name in the entire solution. Still not working

Comment: @HelpASisterOut. I have updated my answer. Try this an let me know if problem still remains

Comment: It now allows me to go into the page even if the Session equals nothing. I put a Msgbox on page load to display the Session values. It displays nothing yet It gives me access to the page.

Comment: Messagebox states the Session("department").toString="" YET breakpoint surpasses the condition If Session("department") IsNot Nothing  !!!

Comment: are you sure  `reader.Item("user_department").ToString` this line returning something. means you are setting value properly.

Answer (score 0):

The key is case sensitive, so change it to "department". Currently it's set to "Department"

Comment: Ok. Are you sure the sessions assignment runs before you reference it in all cases